# How to fix java.lang.NumberFormatException?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keylistener, numberformatexception

```
contactField = new JTextField();     
contactField.setBounds(165, 336, 100, 30);
contactField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
char c = e.getKeyChar(); 

if(!((c >= '0') && (c <= '9') || (c ==
KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||(c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))) {                       
e.consume();
}
} 
});
int contactvalue=Integer.parseInt(contactField.getText());
```

By running this code I am getting:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException:Forinput string: ""
```

Comment: look for `contactField.getText()`

Comment: `contactField.getText()` doesn't return a number format.

Comment: 1) Why is a `contactField` numeric? 2) Try `JSpinner giveNumber = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(20,1,1000, 1));`

Comment: More generally: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  ..

Comment: .. Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 4) For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`. Or for a `JTextComponent`, look to using a `DocumentListener`.

Comment: BTW - is the line `int contactvalue=Integer.parseInt(contactField.getText());` outside or inside the `keyTyped(KeyEvent e)` method? From that dog's breakfast, I cannot tell.

Answer (score 1):

The msg is descriptive:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException:Forinput string: ""

```
Integer.parseInt(contactField.getText());
```

is throwing the exception because **contactField** is empty..

you just can not convert an empty string into an integer.